# 406 error in Spring MVC 4.1.1 while producing JSONArray as response

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-mvc

I am trying to develop an application which consumes Rest API calls via Spring MVC framework. I am stuck in the process of returning JSONArray response. I keep receiving HTTP 406 error: "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers."

I have attached necessary configuration files. I tried few links to resolve issue, but no success. Kindly help me where am I doing wrong.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/userLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONArray userLogin(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject ();
        jsonObj.put("firstname", userservice.getLogin(user));
        jsonArr.put(jsonObj);
        return jsonArr;
    }
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20131018</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.12</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.35</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="********" />

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml"/>
                <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <context:annotation-config />
    </beans>
```

Comment: how you make the request?

Comment: it would be good if u post some more info